# Windowsのバッチファイル内でpsqlを実行した結果をファイルに出力すると不要な改行コードが追加されてしまいます

Tags: windows, command-line

実行環境
OS: Windows11 22H2（OS ビルド 22621.3007）
コマンドプロンプト：Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.3007]
psql:psql (PostgreSQL) 13.7

psqlコマンドを実行してその結果をファイルに出力するWindowsバッチファイルを作成しています。
実行結果をファイルに書き出すと、もともと改行コードがあった場所に改行コードが1つ追加されてしまいます。
クエリの内容は、ログを保存するテーブルのログメッセージが保存されているカラムから値を取り出すというものです。
このような事象がなぜ起こるのか、また起こらないようにする方法をご教示頂きたいです。

```
@echo off

set HOSTNAME=***********
set PORTNUM=5432
set DBNAME=******
set USERNAME=*****
set PGPASSWORD=*********
set "outputFile=output.txt"

psql -h %HOSTNAME% -d %DBNAME% -U %USERNAME% -c "select hoge from fuga where fuga.id = 1" -A -t > output.txt
```

実行結果
以下のように改行の後に1つ改行が追加される形になります。

```
hogehogehogehogehogehogehogehogehogehogehogehogehogehogehogehoge

hogehogehogehogehogehogehogehogehogehogehogehogehogehogehogehogehogehogehogehogehogehogehogehoge
```

Comment: 「もともと改行コードがあった場所に改行コードが1つ追加されてしまいます」1レコードを1行に表示しますので、元のデータ(ログデータ)の末尾に改行コード(`\n`/newline)がある場合には空行が追加されている様に見えることになります。対応としては、`trim` 関数で `newline` を削除することかと思います。

Comment: コメント頂きありがとうございます。  
クエリの内容なのですが、1レコードの1カラムに格納されているログメッセージを1ファイルに出力するというものになります。  
なので、1ファイルに複数レコードが含まれることが無いです。
ログメッセージに含まれる改行コードが、ファイルに書き出されたときに1個から2個に増えているという状態になります。  
DB上では改行コードはLFなのですが、書き出された改行コードはCRLFになっており、そのあたりが怪しいなと思って調べています。